# OpenCv - Contours segments union

Tags: python, opencv, contour

first post here, I've been looking for a solution to solve a problem for days with no results and I ask you for help.
I have enough experience with Python but little experience with OpenCV: I am trying to analyze and get a cutting line to trim a material excluding defects near contour.

On the material image I've been able to obtain the outer contour and the inner contour (for cut) excluding defects near the edge.

The internal contour, however, **despite being perfect in recognizing defects,** **always leaves an offset even from the parts that should not be cut**.

I attach photos to make it clear: in red color outer edge (with defects), in yellow color inner edge to eliminate defects:

**[outer and inner contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEGq8.png)**

In this photo there is an example of the outline I would like to obtain (sorry, done with paint):

**[inner contour aspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YkKQ.png)**

I have tried several searches here and on internet to find ideas and I have studied different approaches (opencv, numpy, scipy, shapely) and in no case I've been able to get the desired results.

In practice, my difficulty is recognize (I think should be a solution) the parallelism between the two contours (which, however, are very segmented), and then making the yellow contour coincide with the external red one when the distance between the two is less than an X value.

Do you have any ideas on the approach to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Show your input images so others can test with it. Also show your code. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda a janky way of doing this, but you can compare the distance from the points on the inner contour to the points on the outer contour and "cling" to the outer contour if the distance is less than some threshold.

You image has some weird artifacting around the edges of the star so I drew my own image in Paint.

Original Image

[image]

After "Cling" (25 distance cutoff)

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# 2d distance
def dist2D(p1, p2):
    dx = p1[0] - p2[0];
    dy = p1[1] - p2[1];
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

# cling to closest point
def cling(point, other_points, cutoff):
    # find closest point
    best_dist = 10000000; # JUST A BIG NUMBER
    best_point = [0,0];
    for op in other_points:
        dist = dist2D(point, op);
        if dist < best_dist:
            best_dist = dist;
            best_point = op[:];

    # if less than cutoff, cling to point
    if best_dist <= cutoff:
        return best_point;
    return point;

# go through each point on inner and cling to nearby outer points
def clingy(inner, outer, cutoff):
    new_inner = [];
    for point in inner:
        point = cling(point, outer, cutoff);
        new_inner.append(point);
    return new_inner;



# load image
img = cv2.imread("my_stars.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# make a mask
mask_outer = cv2.inRange(gray, 0, 1);
mask_inner = cv2.inRange(gray, 2, 254);

# contours OpenCV3.4, if you're using OpenCV 2 or 4, it returns (contours, _)
_, outer, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_outer, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
_, inner, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_inner, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

# just take the first contour
outer = outer[0];
inner = inner[0];

# strip out annoying extra brackets
stripped_inner = np.array([p[0] for p in inner]);
stripped_outer = np.array([p[0] for p in outer]);

# cling
cling_inner = clingy(stripped_inner, stripped_outer, 25);

# add back in annoying brackets
cling_inner = np.array([[p] for p in cling_inner]);

# draw on original image
cv2.drawContours(img, [cling_inner], -1, (240,200,0), -1);

# draw original contour again
cv2.drawContours(img, [inner], -1, (150,100,0), 1);

# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am testing your code and I am finally starting to get results close to what I wanted to achieve.
The only thing is that with large images (3000x3000) the computation is very slow.

Comment: you can try cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE for the findContours function to reduce the number of points it returns. You can further reduce it by using approxPolyDp. However, reducing the number of points could reduce the accuracy of the cling function so you'll have to play around with it to see how much you can reduce it before you don't like how it looks.